# Error 1 Type 'MemoryStream' is not defined. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im usign this code:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value)
info.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(ms)
End Using
```

And i got this error:

```
Error   1   Type 'MemoryStream' is not defined.
```

Can you help me? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared ms like so before using it?

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
```

and also use the namespace

```
Imports System.IO
```